# Get a node along with parent node without siblings using xpath

Tags: java, xpath

Sample XML:

`<animals>`
`<cat>cat</cat>`
   `<dog>dog</dog>`
   `<lion>lion</lion>`
`</animals>`

Suppose if i search for the element "dog", the expected result is 
`<animals>`
`<dog>dog</dog>`
`<animals>`

I want only the parent node(animals) and the searched node(dog). Siblings(cat,lion) should not be displayed.How can i achieve this through XPath?

Answer (score 2):

The easy answer is: you can't, because XPath selects nodes and does not mutate the DOM.

You can do this with an xslt transformation.

For example you can emit all nodes but will filter animals node by letting in only the one with a cat inside and removing all other animals:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" ></xsl:output>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//animals[cat]">
    <xsl:comment>CAT animals</xsl:comment>
    <animals>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="cat"/>
    </animals>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//animals[not(cat)]">
    <xsl:comment>Skipped</xsl:comment>
  </xsl:template>



  <xsl:template match="cat">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you whant to mutate you current dom element you could simply select all unwanted nodes and remove them.

```
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    NodeList unitAnimals = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//animals[cat]/*[not(self::cat)]", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for(int i = 0; i<unitAnimals.getLength();i++){
        Node unitAnimal = unitAnimals.item(i);
        Node parentNode = unitAnimal.getParentNode();
        parentNode.removeChild(unitAnimal);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That should be enough

```
(/animals/dog)[1]
```